# getting a bad request error when trying to send an axios post request to a django server

Tags: django, vue.js, axios

Im working with vuejs3 and django rest frame. i used apiView in ,y django view, here is my view

```
class BlogPostView(APIView):
    
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        blogpost=BlogPost.objects.all().order_by('?')
        serializer=BlogPostSerializer(blogpost, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
        
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer=BlogPostSerializer(data=request.data)
        
        print(request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=statis.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and here is my axios code

```
axios({
            url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/blogs/',
            method:'post',
            data:{
                title,
                content:ckData.value.data,
                category:'programmimg',
                status:1,
                publisher:1
            },
            transformRequest(data){
                data=JSON.stringify(data)
                return data
            },
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'Authorization':'JWT fefege...',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            
            }
        }).then((response)=>{
            
        })
```

getting a 400, bad request when the request is sent to the server

it seems the serializer isnt valid, but im using modelsSerializer, all required field are filled with valid type
anyone with a solution, i ll appreciate

Comment: You can just check the details of the 400 message to know the source of the issue.

Comment: Can you provide the urls.py and the error log for the 400 message ?